# Angular routing in Heroku from external file

Tags: angularjs, node.js, heroku

I've been working on a relatively simple MEAN stack app, and now want to host it with Heroku. I'm 90% of the way there, but I can't seem to get state / page routing working. I'm using Yeoman, Gulp, and Bower, if that helps. It works fine locally of course, but I can't find information on specifying the router file for Heroku. I have a feeling I might be missing a simple "server.use()" statement, but it could also be a change that I need to make in my package.json. I've already tried including the dist/ folder in the repository, as many forums suggest with this issue, to no avail. The back end works fine (except for using mLab), so the Heroku app is at least somewhat configured correctly.

This is my server:

```
// Modules
var gzippo = require("gzippo");
var express = require("express");
var server = express();
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongo = require('mongodb');
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

// Controllers and Services
var topic = require('./controllers/topic');
var auth = require('./controllers/auth');
var cors = require('./services/cors');

// Middleware
server.use(cors);
server.use(bodyParser.json());
server.use(server.router);
app.use(function(req, res) {
    // Use res.sendfile, as it streams instead of reading the file into memory.
    res.sendfile(__dirname + '/public/index.html');
});

server.get('/', topic.test);

server.get('/topic/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    res.id = req.params.id;
    next();
}, topic.get);

server.post('/topic/add', topic.post);

server.post('/topic/:id/:side/reason/add', function(req, res, next) {
    res.id = req.params.id;
    res.side = req.params.side;
    next();
}, topic.addReason);

server.get('/user/add', auth.add);

server.post('/user/login', auth.login);

// process.env.MONGOLAB_URI ||
// TODO: Protect mLab login credentials

// Mongo connection
mongoose.connect("<redacted>", function(err, db) {
    // mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017", function(err, db) {

    if (!err) {
        console.log("Connected to Mongo");
    } else {
        console.log("MONGO ERROR: " + err);
    }
})

// Server listener
server.listen(process.env.PORT || 4000, function() {
    server.use(express.static(__dirname));
    // server.use(gzippo.staticGzip("" + __dirname + "/dist"));
    console.log("Server listening on port " + process.env.PORT);
});

// server.listen(4000, function() {
//  console.log("Server listening on port 4000");
// });
```

package.json:

```
{
  "name": "mystance",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "The world's opinions in three boxes.",
  "main": "/back-end/server.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "ng": "ng",
    "build": "cd front-end && gulp build",
    "postinstall": "cd front-end && bower install"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/connergillette/mystance.git"
  },
  "author": "Conner Gillette",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/connergillette/mystance/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/connergillette/mystance#readme",
  "engines": {
    "node": "6.10.3"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.0.2",
    "@angular/common": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^4.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^4.0.0",
    "angular-animate": "^1.6.5",
    "async": "^2.5.0",
    "babel-core": "~6.7.4",
    "babel-loader": "~6.2.4",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "~6.6.0",
    "body-parser": "^1.17.2",
    "bower": "^1.8.0",
    "browser-sync": "~2.9.11",
    "browser-sync-spa": "~1.0.3",
    "chalk": "~1.1.1",
    "del": "~2.0.2",
    "eslint-loader": "~1.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-angular": "~0.12.0",
    "estraverse": "~4.1.0",
    "express": "^4.15.3",
    "gulp": "~3.9.0",
    "gulp-angular-templatecache": "~1.8.0",
    "gulp-autoprefixer": "~3.0.2",
    "gulp-cssnano": "~2.1.1",
    "gulp-eslint": "~1.0.0",
    "gulp-filter": "~3.0.1",
    "gulp-flatten": "~0.2.0",
    "gulp-htmlmin": "~1.3.0",
    "gulp-inject": "~3.0.0",
    "gulp-load-plugins": "~0.10.0",
    "gulp-protractor": "~2.1.0",
    "gulp-rename": "~1.2.2",
    "gulp-replace": "~0.5.4",
    "gulp-rev": "~6.0.1",
    "gulp-rev-replace": "~0.4.2",
    "gulp-sass": "~2.0.4",
    "gulp-size": "~2.0.0",
    "gulp-sourcemaps": "~1.6.0",
    "gulp-uglify": "~1.4.1",
    "gulp-useref": "~3.0.3",
    "gulp-util": "~3.0.6",
    "gzippo": "^0.2.0",
    "http-proxy-middleware": "~0.9.0",
    "jwt-simple": "^0.5.1",
    "karma": "~0.13.10",
    "karma-coverage": "~0.5.2",
    "karma-jasmine": "~0.3.6",
    "karma-ng-html2js-preprocessor": "~0.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "~0.2.1",
    "karma-phantomjs-shim": "~1.2.0",
    "lodash": "~3.10.1",
    "main-bower-files": "~2.9.0",
    "moment": "^2.18.1",
    "mongoose": "^4.11.0",
    "ng-annotate-loader": "0.0.10",
    "phantomjs": "~1.9.18",
    "uglify-save-license": "~0.4.1",
    "webpack-stream": "~2.1.1",
    "wiredep": "~2.2.2",
    "yo": "^2.0.0"
  }
}
```

index.route.js:

```
export function routerConfig($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
    'ngInject';
    $stateProvider
        .state('home', {
            url: '/',
            templateUrl: 'app/main/main.html',
            controller: 'MainController',
            controllerAs: 'main'
        })

        .state('topic-add', {
            url: '/topic/add',
            templateUrl: 'app/topic/topic-add.html',
            controller: 'TopicController',
            controllerAs: 'topic'
        })

        .state('reason-add', {
            url: '/topic/:id/:side/reason/add',
            templateUrl: 'app/topic/reason-add.html',
            controller: 'TopicController',
            controllerAs: 'topic'
        })

        .state('topic', {
            url: '/topic/:id',
            templateUrl: 'app/topic/topic.html',
            controller: 'TopicController',
            controllerAs: 'topic'
        });

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}
```

I've never deployed a NodeJS app before, so apologies if I've made some (or many) stupid mistakes. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check this: https://github.com/heroku/node-js-getting-started

Usually all we need to do is to add the following to server js file:

```
app.set('port', (process.env.PORT || 5000));
pp.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  console.log('Node app is running on port', app.get('port'));
});
```

Comment: I already have the server running fine - that's not the issue. Getting front-end routing to work is what I'm struggling with. Thanks for the response though.